# XPath for button using unique identifier with strong tag

Tags: xpath

I am attempting to find a robust xpath to click a button in the screenshot below

The button I wish to click is the blue +

[image]

The HTML of the element is made up on the following

```
  <td class="text-left">
                                                <button ng- 
   hide="!efsEditRole_RoleAssignedToUser" ng-disabled="!appSummaryVm.OR_fieldOptionsArray.length" id="btnAddFieldOption_2_OR" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="appSummaryVm.addOption($index, 'OR'); appSummaryVm.addOptionsByField(OR_field.fieldId, 'OR');" title="Add Option" aria-hidden="false">
                                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                                </button>
                                                <strong>FN 3/087/062/2</strong><br><strong>MEA 1.53ha</strong>&nbsp;<strong>
                                                    Tranche 2
                                                    <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" title="The FCAT tranche year displayed is the FCAT currently applied to the field. FCAT determines the EFS field category and the eligibility of EFS(W) Options.  FCAT Tranche 1 = 2017. FCAT Tranche 2 = 2018. FCAT Tranche 3 = 2019.">
                                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </strong>
                                            </td>
```

I have attempted to locate the button  using the following xpath but it is not working. I need to be able to select the button for the specific FN unique identifier.

```
//button[@title='Add Option']//strong[normalize-space(text())='FN 3/087/062/2']
```

Any help would be appracited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strong` node is not a *descendant*, but *sibling* of `button`, so you can use below XPath to locate required button:

```
//button[@title='Add Option' and following-sibling::strong[normalize-space(text())='FN 3/087/062/2']]
```